Sync Between Azure DevOps Git Repo and GitHub Repo
I have imported GitHub repo into Azure DevOps. But later I made changes in Azure DevOps code and also created new repo and pull requests in Azure DevOps, and I want to make all of these in a sync with GitHub.
And also, please provide inputs to do the same sync in Vise versa. To get the latest code from github to Azure DevOps.
I tried to build a pipeline using couple of YAML code to make a sync, even after the code ran successfully, I am unable to migrate the code, new repo and pull requests. Please provide solution with Documents and sample code.
Yaml Code1 used:
# Define the trigger for the pipeline, which specifies when it should run.
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - feature-*  # Trigger on changes in the develop branch

# Define the pool of agents that the pipeline should run on.
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'  # Use an Ubuntu agent

# Define environment variables for Git credentials.
variables:
  GitHub_Repository_URL: 'https://username:token@github.com/githuburl'
  GIT_USERNAME: 'username'
  GIT_PASSWORD: 'token'

# Define the steps of the pipeline.
steps:
  # Step to checkout the code from the current repository.
- checkout: self  # Checkout the code from the current repository

  # Step to configure Git credentials.
- script: |
    git config --global credential.helper cache
    git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout=3600'
    git config --global user.name "$(GIT_USERNAME)"
    git config --global user.email "email"
    git remote add github $(GitHub_Repository_URL)  # Add GitHub repository as a remote
    git fetch github  # Fetch from GitHub
  displayName: 'Configure Git Credentials and Fetch Changes'  # Display name for this step

  # Step to synchronize code changes with GitHub for feature branches.
- script: |
    for branch in $(git branch -r --list "origin/feature-*"); do
      branch_name=$(echo $branch | cut -d'/' -f2)
      if ! git ls-remote --exit-code --heads github $branch_name; then
        git checkout -b $branch_name github/main  # Create a new local branch from GitHub main
        git push -u github $branch_name  # Push new branch to GitHub
      else
        git checkout -b $branch_name github/main  # Create a new local branch from GitHub main
        git pull origin $branch_name  # Pull changes from the branch in Azure DevOps
        git push github $branch_name  # Push changes to GitHub
      fi
    done
  displayName: 'Sync Changes with GitHub for Feature Branches'  # Display name for this step

  # Step to synchronize code changes with GitHub for new feature branches.
- script: |
    for branch in $(git branch -r --list "origin/feature-*"); do
      branch_name=$(echo $branch | cut -d'/' -f2)
      if ! git ls-remote --exit-code --heads github $branch_name; then
        git checkout -b $branch_name github/main  # Create a new local branch from GitHub main
        git push -u github $branch_name  # Push new branch to GitHub
      else
        git checkout -b $branch_name github/main  # Create a new local branch from GitHub main
        git pull origin $branch_name  # Pull changes from the branch in Azure DevOps
        git push github $branch_name  # Push changes to GitHub
      fi
    done
  displayName: 'Sync Changes with GitHub for New Feature Branches'  # Display name for this step

Yaml Code 2 used:
# Define the trigger (adjust branch patterns as needed)
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - feature-*

# Define the pool
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

# Securely access PAT using Azure DevOps secrets
variables:
  GitHub_Repository_URL: 'https://username:token@github.com/githuburl'
  GIT_USERNAME: 'username'
  GIT_PASSWORD: 'token'


# Define steps
steps:
- checkout: self

- script: |
    git config --global credential.helper cache
    git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout=3600'
    git config --global user.name "$(GIT_USERNAME)"  # Consider using a generic username (optional)
    git config --global user.email "email"  # Consider using a generic email (optional)
    git remote add github $(GitHub_Repository_URL)  # Add GitHub repository as a remote


- script: |
    for branch in $(git branch -r --list "origin/feature-*"); do
      branch_name=$(echo $branch | cut -d'/' -f2)

        # Check if branch exists on GitHub
        if ! git ls-remote --exit-code --heads github $branch_name; then
          git checkout -b $branch_name origin/$branch_name  # Checkout new branch from Azure DevOps
          git push -u github $branch_name  # Push new branch to GitHub
        else
          # Existing branch - existing logic for pulling/pushing
          git checkout $branch_name  # Directly checkout existing branch
          git pull origin $branch_name  # Pull changes from Azure DevOps
          git push github $branch_name  # Push changes to GitHub
        fi
      done
  displayName: 'Sync Code Changes with GitHub'

Thanks In Advance.

Hi. You have the same step twice, how is that going to help? Furthermore, you would need to describe the actual problem in more detail, e.g., provide some error messages or say where exactly you are struggling.

Pipeline ran successfully without any error, but code didn't get migrated to GitHub from Azure DevOps

Okay, you have now updated the question and posted an updated code snippet. This makes the question even harder to understand, because now we will see two snippets without any information about how they are related. I have opened the history to see this, but most people won't. Regarding the actual problem: even if the pipeline ran "successfully", you can still post the outputs of the pipeline.

To sync from GitHub repo to Azure repo, there are two suggestions.

Every commit in the GitHub repo will trigger the DevOps pipeline to synchronize the repo. You need to add a yaml file under each branch of your GitHub repo.

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      git clone --mirror https://<GitHub PAT>@github.com/<GitHub org name>/<GitHub repo name>.git
      cd $(build.sourcesdirectory)/<GitHub repo name>.git
      git remote add origin1 https://$(System.AccessToken)@dev.azure.com/<DevOps org name>/<DevOps project name>/_git/<Azure repo name>
      git push -u origin1  --all
  env:
    AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(System.AccessToken)



Use Scheduled triggers of the pipeline to schedule the synchronization. You need to add the following yaml file to the main branch of your GitHub repo.

schedules:
- cron: 0 0,6,12,18 * * *
  displayName: Trigger every 6 hours
  branches:
    include: 
    - main
 
  always: true 
 
trigger:
- none
 
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest
steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      git clone --mirror https://<GitHub PAT>@github.com/<GitHub org name>/<GitHub repo name>.git
      cd $(build.sourcesdirectory)/<GitHub repo name>.git
      git remote add origin1 https://$(System.AccessToken)@dev.azure.com/<DevOps org name>/<DevOps project name>/_git/<Azure repo name>
      git push -u origin1  --all
  env:
    AZURE_DEVOPS_EXT_PAT: $(System.AccessToken)


The source code of your DevOps pipeline should be your GitHub repo.
If you want to sync Azure repo to GitHub repo, you can also use the similar git commands. There is a blog Sync Azure Devops repo with GitHub repo for your reference.
